# Удаление из списка элементов в парсере

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, bs4

Парни, пишу парсер, вот у меня сформировался список c айпишниками('More information about IP)
Kак сделать так ,что бы из списка удалились элементы, которые обозначены `None`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='https://www.ip-adress.com/proxy-list'

def get_html(url):
    r=requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def soup(html):
    b=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    print(b)
    # b.find_all('a')
    # b.find_all('href')
    for link in b.find_all('a'):
        # print(link.get('title'))
        lin=link.get('title')
        # print(lin)
        linklist=[]
        linklist.append(lin)
        print(linklist)

def main():
    soup(get_html(url))

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: так а где в коде сам список?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перед добавление IP в список, добавьте проверку по наличию значения:

```
...
if lin != None:
    linklist.append(lin)
...
```

или просто

```
if lin:
    linklist.append(lin)
...
```

К тому же, вот этим действием:

```
    for link in b.find_all('a'):
        linklist=[]
```

вы опустошаете список linklist при каждой итерации, и всегда будет выводиться список из одного элемента. Причесал код немного:

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url='https://www.ip-adress.com/proxy-list'

def get_html(url):
    r=requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def soup(html):
    b=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    linklist=[]
    for link in b.find_all('a'):
        lin=link.get('title')
        if lin:    
            linklist.append(lin)
    return linklist

def main():
    result = soup(get_html(url))
    pprint(result)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое